# Jquery - How to select an option generated by PHP

Tags: php, jquery, select, include

I got a select which is generated by php.

```
<div id="panneauModifAnnonce" class="divAdmin">
<form id="modifierAnnonceForm">

<label class ="labelEmail">ID</label>
<input id="inp_idAnnonce" class ="inputEmail" />

<label class ="labelEmail">Titre</label>
<input id ="inp_titreAnnonce" class ="inputEmail" />

<label class ="labelEmail">Description</label>
<textarea id ="inp_txtDescription" class ="inputEmail" maxlength="500" ></textarea>

<label class ="labelEmail">Taille</label>
<select id ="inp_selectTaille" class ="inputEmail">
<option value="" selected="selected"> </option>
<optgroup label="Taille">
<option value="XS-36">XS-36 </option>
<option value="S-38">S-38 </option>
<option value="M-40">M-40 </option>

</optgroup>
<optgroup label="Pointure">                                                 
<option value="36">36 </option>
<option value="37">37 </option>
<option value="38">38 </option>

</optgroup>                                                
</select>

<label class ="labelEmail">Couleur</label>
<input id="inp_couleurAnnonce" class ="inputEmail" />

<label class ="labelEmail">Marque</label>
<input id ="inp_marqueAnnonce" class ="inputEmail" />

<label class ="labelEmail">Prix</label>
<input id ="inp_prixAnnonce" class ="inputEmail" />

<label class ="labelEmail">Annonceur</label>
<input id ="inp_annonceur" class ="inputEmail" />

<label class ="labelEmail">Catégories</label>
<select id ="inp_selectCatAnnonces" class ="inputEmail">
<option value="" selected="selected"> </option>
   <?php include_once 'includes/inc_selectCategories.php'; ?>
</select>

<label class ="labelEmail">Validité</label>
<div>
   <input type="radio" name="rad_valid" id ="inp_radValide" value ="1" /><span>Oui</span>
   <input type="radio" name="rad_valid" id ="inp_radinvalide" value ="0" /><span>Non</span>
</div>
<input type="submit" name="submit_modifier" value="Enregistrer les modifications" />
<input type="button" name ="btn_annulerModif" value ="Annuler" />
</form>
</div><!-- panneauModifAnnonce-->
```

I'm trying to get and select the value with jquery but it seems like jquery dont like the include function. I've read some other post but I think that they dont talk about the same problem. Any help would be great! Thanks!

Jquery Code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btn_modifierAnnonce").click(function(){

        $.each($("input[type='checkbox']:checked"), function(){
            //attribution des données au champs correspondant et sauvegarde de la valeur du champs
            var id = $(this).parent().parent().find("td:eq(0)");
            $("#inp_idAnnonce").val(id.text());

            var titre = $(this).parent().parent().find("td:eq(1)");    //  eq(2) = cherche le 2è element qui correspond au sélécteur                                                
            $("#inp_titreAnnonce").val(titre.text());

            var description = $(this).parent().parent().find("td:eq(2)");
            $("#inp_txtDescription").val(description.text()); 

            var taille = $(this).parent().parent().find("td:eq(4)");            
            $("#inp_selectTaille option[value="+taille.text()+"]").attr('selected','selected');

            var couleur = $(this).parent().parent().find("td:eq(5)");
            $("#inp_couleurAnnonce").val(couleur.text());

            var marque = $(this).parent().parent().find("td:eq(6)");
            $("#inp_marqueAnnonce").val(marque.text());

            var prix = $(this).parent().parent().find("td:eq(8)");
            $("#inp_prixAnnonce").val(prix.text()); 

            //it doesnt work only for this case.. 
            var categorie = $(this).parent().parent().find("td:eq(7)");
            $('#inp_selectCatAnnonces option[value="'+categorie.text()+'"]').attr('selected','selected');

            var annonceur = $(this).parent().parent().find("td:eq(9)");
            $("#inp_annonceur").val(prix.text());

            var validite = $(this).parent().parent().find("td:eq(10)");
            if(validite.text()=="1"){
                $('#inp_radValide').attr('checked','checked');                        
            }
            else{
                $('#inp_radinvalide').attr('checked','checked');                        
            }


        })//fin $.each(input select)
    })//fin $(#btn_modifierAnnonce).click
 })//fin document.ready
```

I get the right value with the var categorie but I cant autoselect the value in the select

Comment: I hope your jquery code executes after the php has finished loading. Load your page in Google Chrome with the Console open, check and post what error it gives you.

Comment: When does your javascript code execute? Are you enclosing it in a doc.ready method?

Comment: You actually don't have to go through the trouble by setting the `selected` attribute manually. You can simply do: `$('#yourEl').val('some value')` and it will select the right `option` for you automatically.

Comment: I am actually enclosing a doc.ready method. I've got others input and they are correctly loaded. The only problem is with this select (I got an other select but in HTML code so it works well)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/874381/w00 I've already tried this method but it doesnt work :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys that I've bothered you : I found it myself.

I check at the PHP script and the values of the options were the id's not the correct value!

Thanks to everyone!

Answer (score 0):

That's what the `val()` function is for:

```
$("#inp_selectCatAnnonces").val('newlyselectedvalue');
```

and get the selected value with:

```
$("#inp_selectCatAnnonces").val();
```

Answer (score 0):

You might have a problem with quotes and the value attribute. Try combining simple and double quotes like this:

```
$('#inp_selectCatAnnonces option[value="'+categorie.text()+'"]').attr('selected', true);
```

Comment: Are you sure the content of `categorie.text()` is the correct one? What do you get printing it by console?

Comment: -> Yes, I've copied/pasted your solution.

Comment: I've done an alert(categorie.text()) and it returns the correct value (it came from a table). What I'm trying to do is getting the value from the table and then, in a form, selecting the option which matches with the value. For example if I have "jeans" in the categorie's table, the form automatically select the "jeans" option... Sorry for my very bad english.. Hope I'm understable

Comment: I have updated my answer. Take a look now. Try setting the `selected` attribute to `true` instead of `selected`.

Answer (score 0):

To start just simply remove the `selected="selected"`. Because the first element is **selected** by default anyway.

Then include your `includes/inc_selectCategories.php` like you're doing. Make sure the populated data is valid HTML! Do this with FireBug or a similair tool. (F12 in most browsers).

Then change your Javascript code to this:

```
// On DOM ready. This is very important!
$(function() {
    var categorie = $(this).parent().parent().find("td:eq(7)");
    // console.log ( categorie.text() ); // Make sure it returns a valid value!!

    // Select the right value from the dropdown
    $('#inp_selectCatAnnonces').val(categorie.text());
});
```

Just make sure you atleast `alert` the value that you're trying to get from `categorie.text()`. I suspect that the value isn't exactly matching the value from the `<select>` list. Also make sure that the `values` in there are correct.

here is an example that illustrates this behavior:

http://jsfiddle.net/3g4PU/